# Resistance between two points on a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

My attempt at this question:

First, I redrew the circuit

[image]

And then I omitted the bottom resistor because I assumed the current would not opt to  go through the longer path with higher resistance.[image]

Answer:

$\left({1\over R}+{1\over2R}\right)^{-1}
=\frac23R$

Comment: You should not assume that no current will flow through the last leg. That leg has a lower resistance, so more of the incoming current at the left-middle junction will enter it. (see Kirchoff's current rule)

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Comment: If i include the 3rd resistor, I get 2/5R, which isn't an option. So of course I'm going to have to omit one of the resistors, but I'm not sure which one I should omit considering the two points being considered.When I consider A the input and B the ouput, I once again reach the answer of 2/3R.

Comment: @chaosdig5...It's $\frac{3R}{5}$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your circuit representation:
[image: Resistance between A and B]
Here is the calculation formula:
$$R_{TOT} = {1\over{{1\over R}+{1\over {1\over {1\over{R}}+{1\over R}}+R}}}$$

You should get:

$R_{TOT} = 3R/5$

Comment: Nice one...But you could've simulated the picture in a different way....

Comment: @NehalSamee How so?

Comment: @Dlamini...You can consider the end points of the resistance-less wires same...The answer would be same...